# What champion abilities allow Yasuo to use his ultimate, Last Breath?

Tags: league-of-legends

There is of course the obvious ones such as Janna's Howling Gale or Malphite's Unstoppable Force. Are there anymore less obvious abilities that Yasuo can use to capitalize on?

Comment: What would be a less obvious ability? Anything that knocks up a champion counts for his ult.

Comment: There are some edge cases, one I noticed while playing Draven is his Stand Aside counts for Yasuo

Answer (score 27, accepted):

He can use it with every knock-up/knock-back. So, from all champions:

- **Aatrox: Q**
- Ahri: none
- Akali: none
- **Alistar: Q, W**
- Amumu: none
- **Anivia: W**
- Annie: none
- Ashe: none
- **Aurelion Sol: R**
- **Azir: R**
- Bard: none
- **Blitz: Q, E**
- Brand: none
- **Braum: R**
- Cait: none
- **Camille: R**
- Cassiopeia: none
- **Cho'gath: Q**
- **Corki: Package W**
- **Darius: E**
- **Diana: E**
- Dr. Mundo: none
- **Draven: E**
- Ekko: none
- Elise: none
- Evelynn: none
- Ezreal: none
- Fiddlesticks: none
- Fiora: none
- **Fizz: R**
- **Galio: E, R**
- Gangplank: none
- Garen: none
- **Gnar: R**
- **Gragas: E, R**
- Graves: none
- **Hecarim: E**
- Heimerdinger: none
- Illaoi: none
- Irelia: none
- **Ivern: R (Daisy's 3rd attack can knock up)**
- **Janna: Q, R**
- **Jarvan: E+Q combo**
- Jax: none
- **Jayce: E (hammer stance)**
- Jhin: none
- Jinx: none
- **Kalista: R**
- Karma: none
- Karthus: none
- Kassadin: none
- Katarina: none
- Kayle: none
- **Kayn: W (Rhaast only)**
- Kennen: none
- Kha'Zix: none
- Kindred: none
- **Kled: Q, R**
- Kog'maw: none
- LeBlanc: none
- **Lee Sin: R**
- Leona: none
- Lissandra: none
- Lucian: none
- **Lulu: R**
- Lux: none
- **Malphite: R**
- Malzahar: none
- **Maokai: Q**
- Master Yi: none
- Miss Fortune: none
- Mordekaiser: none
- Morgana: none
- **Nami: Q, R**
- Nasus: none
- **Nautilus: Q, R**
- Nidalee: none
- Nocturne: none
- Nunu: none
- Olaf: none
- **Orianna: R**
- **Poppy: E**
- Pantheon: none
- **Quinn: E**
- **Rakan: W**
- **Rammus: Q**
- **Rek'Sai: W (burrowed)**
- Rengar: none
- Renekton: none
- **Riven: 3rd Q**
- Rumble: none
- Ryze: none
- **Sejuani: Q**
- Shaco: none
- Shen: none
- **Shyvana: R**
- **Singed: E**
- **Sion: Q, R**
- Sivir: none
- Skarner: none
- Sona: none
- Soraka: none
- Swain: none
- **Syndra: E**
- Tahm Kench: none
- Talon: none
- **Taliyah: W**
- Taric: none
- Teemo: none
- **Thresh: Q, E**
- **Tristana: R**
- **Trundle: E**
- Tryndamere: none
- Twisted Fate: none
- Twitch: none
- Udyr: none
- **Urgot: E**
- Varus: none
- **Vayne: E**
- Veigar: none
- **Vel' Koz: E**
- **Vi: Q, R**
- **Viktor: W (upgraded)**
- **Volibear: Q**
- Warwick: none
- **Wukong: R**
- Xayah: none
- Xerath: none
- **Xin Zhao: Q, R**
- **Yasuo: 3rd Q (duuh...)**
- Yorick: none
- **Zac: Q, E, R**
- Zed: none
- **Ziggs: W**
- Zilean: none
- **Zyra: R**
- **Blasting plant knock-up**: Only works when Yasuo or his ally hits the plant that knocks up an opponent. [Reddit Thread with discussion and confirmation](https://www.reddit.com/r/YasuoMains/comments/5c9vq3/psa_yasuo_ult_interaction_with_blast_cone/)

**Things that didn't work for me but still are knock-ups somehow:**

- Vilemaw(Big creepy spider in TT): Net attack
- Baron: Knock-up

Comment: dat effort :D +1

Comment: ok.. nice list. has anyone tried out if you can ulti jumping rengar, kazix or jax?

Comment: Those abilities won't work since the Champions using them aren't considered airborne. As far as I know there are only a few slows (VI, Varus), roots (Xerath), and silences (Rumble) as self cc but no real knockup or knockback.

Comment: Regarding syndra's E, is it possible to use yasuo's ulti on an enemy hit only by a sphere, outside the cone range, or must he be hit by the actual spell?

Comment: @Alessandro It's possible but it's a rather short amount of time the enemy is mid-air (about 0.1s or less) so you have to be pretty quick.

Comment: gnar? what about him?

Comment: What about Kleds chain? It has some sort of a pull, similar to Thresh flay. Also you have Velkoz 2 times in the list

Comment: @Pyjong You can't ult champs who are using jumping abilities.

Answer (score 2):

It works on any unit that is in the air.

So if an ability say knocking target into the air it will work.

a few champs that come to mind:

- Blitzcrank
- Alistar
- Malphite
- Janna
- Cho gath
- Nautilus
- Aatrox
- Jarvan
- Zyra
- Wukong
- Thresh Death Sentence and Flay

There are probably more, but it will work with these champs

Comment: Don't forget good old Xin :P

Comment: This should be a wiki question

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of abilities that actually work with Yasuo, despite the fact that they are not knock-ups. Draven's Stand Aside, Tristana's ultimate, Riven's third 'Q' strike, and the list goes on. Basically anyone with any ability that knocks someone back or moves the person will work with Yasuo's ultimate.

Comment: Yepp it seems to be _any_ sort of displacement, not just knock-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Any skill that knocks up an enemy champ even for a millisecond such as the tip of a vi q or vayne e 
Most movement displacements are knock ups

Comment: This doesn't add any information already provided in other answers

Answer (score 0):

It doent show it and you have to be really fast, but if you use the iceberg ability and the enemy is in the very centre, you can use his ult. Its hard to do, generally i just spam it because you have such a small time gap to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot Anivia.  A fast Yasuo can ult off the push that Anivia's wall does when cast underneath a target.