# Does Anivia's wall grant an assist?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was surprised to note recently that I apparently got an assist as Anivia for doing nothing other than blocking an enemy champion with Ice Wall, but can't be 100% certain that I did not AA at all. There seems to be conflicting information on whether the wall does or doesn't grant assists when I look online, and most sources are outdated.

So, what is the actual behavior of the wall and can it grant assists when that is the only contribution towards a champion kill?

Comment: At one time, abilities like these did 1 damage to ensure that an assist was given. I'm not sure if it does damage anymore, but I'm fairly certain it can give assists.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv They still do 1 true damage. As I recall, the reasoning was so that if you cast it in turret range, it would aggro the turret onto you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place a wall on the opponent and your opponent gets affected (moves), **yes** you will get an assist.

If there happens to be a wall and your opponent touches it, you will **not** get an assist.

Comment: not many ppl know you can actually interrupt channeling with anivia's wall.

Comment: I think touching the wall counts as an assist as well.

Comment: @Hackworth no... unlike Trundle's pillar of filth (former...) the wall does not apply any effects after casting, and thus will not grant an assist.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the wall right (which isn't that easy) you will knock back an enemy and thus you will gain an assist. Note however that champions that ignore Unit collision will **not** be knocked back, since the wall is basically made of minions when you take it to the programming behind the game (Only when it spawns though).

So you won't knock back a Fizz, Hecarim or anyone with Ghost. Also Anivias wall doesn't count as a knockback for Yasuos ultimate. You can Interrupt a channeled spell or even a Shyvana ult when you time it right but you won't be able to use it as a knockup/knockback like let's say the center of a Trundle pillar which really works as a knockback when you hit the center.

If you might remember the old Trundle pillar: that's exactly how it works. Its just "Moving a champion aside". Not a real type of CC but it still affects movement and channeled abilities.

Comment: didn't know yasuo's ult worked with knockbacks.

Comment: [These](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146107/what-other-champion-abilities-can-yasuo-use-with-his-last-breath/147516#147516) are the abilities that yasuo can use with his  Ult. So it's pretty much everything that knocks the enemy in only the slightest way ^^

Answer (score 0):

Anivia's wall does 1 true damage to grant the assist when put on a target Cf patch notes (can't link it to you cause I'm at work ;-) )